# Pimcore ajax to call back-end action

Tags: php, ajax, pimcore

How can I make Jquery ajax to back-end action in controller
my js likes blew

```
$(function () {
    $("#spanid").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: XSiteUrl + "/demo",
            data: {
                username: "gq"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

and my controller's action code as blew
[clientCallDemoAction is my action I want to call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffa4q.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the snippet you posted is from a website controller, then the simplest way is to request this URL:

```
"?controller=demo&action=client-call"
```

See this:
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE/Magic+Parameters

You could also create a static route or a document to achieve the same thing. Static route is of course a better solution of these two.
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14551636

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the real effect  I want to call a function

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean. But you should just do something like this:
`$.ajax({  url: "?controller=demo&action=client-call"` ...

Comment: Yes I did it like your ajax but when in document page I code ajax to call my   controller action but I does not work well .

Comment: Finally I resolve this issue,  by adding this code in my action $this->disableViewAutoRender();

Comment: @IgorBenko Hello, can you share the link again? Links in the answer are not working.

Comment: @Archana the information in my answer is very outdated as it was relevant only for very old version of Pimcore. For the current versions of Pimcore you should just use Symfony Routes. See more abuot this here: https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/MVC/Routing_and_URLs/index.html